# Rename a .datasource file in a WCF service reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2010

**Background:**
I have a C# client side app consuming a service resource.  When I set it up I name the client side api for the service resource.  (For example: *CoreLibraryUserAuthentication*)

Then Visual Studio goes to make the files for the service reference.  One of them is the *.datasource* file.  It ends up being:

> MyProjectThatIs26CharsLong.CoreLibraryUserAuthentication.32CharServiceNmeThatIAmConsuming.datasource

That, combined with a fairly long path (159 Chars) leads to a really long file name and path (261 chars).  This is over the limit of what TFS will allow.  (The issue is really more complex that this, having to do with history and migration of the project, but going into that is more detail than is needed.)

**What I need:**
A way to rename that datasource file to something more reasonable.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need [that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439364/what-are-the-wcf-service-reference-datasource-files)? Direct binding to UI is not great for WCF wich provides raw DTO. Add that file in ignore list in you version control or just delete it.

Sometimes a problem doesn't have to be solved at all.