# How to do what head, tail, more, less, sed do in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

On windows, using Powershell, what are the equivalent commands to linux's `head`, `tail`, `more`, `less` and `sed`?

Comment: log file is too big, about several MBytes. It's too hard to view by notepad.exe.

Comment: If you are using `notepad` as your base I would suggest looking at alternative text editors, there are plenty of (both free and paid) alternatives. All are superior to notepad (albeit that's not much of a challenge).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell vs. Unix Shells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573623/powershell-vs-unix-shells)

Comment: I deal with large files and I use/install Vim which proves much faster than any other tool I have used.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`Get-Content` (alias: `gc`) is your usual option for reading a text file. You can then filter further with other commands, e.g. (Alias `select` -> `Select-Object`):

```
gc log.txt | select -first 10 # head
gc -TotalCount 10 log.txt     # also head
gc log.txt | select -last 10  # tail
gc -Tail 10 log.txt           # also tail (since PSv3), also much faster than above option
gc log.txt | more             # or less if you have it installed
gc log.txt | %{ $_ -replace '\d+', '($0)' }         # sed
```

This works well enough for small files, larger ones (more than a few MiB) are probably a bit slow.

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) include some cmdlets for specialised file stuff (e.g. Get-FileTail).

Comment: Holy cow, this is maxing out my CPU to do a `-last 2` on a 1GB CSV. Hot beverage: ☕

Comment: @mlissner: If you're on PowerShell v3 you can use `Get-Content -Tail 2` instead. That's definitely faster.

Comment: `gc log.txt | %{ $_ -replace '\d+', '($0)' }         # sed` that is not actually fully the sed tool as it does not put content back. It needs Set-Content.

Comment: @Artem: And parentheses in that case. I wasn't aware that sed writes anything by itself; I've seen it used mostly to change stuff in a stream.

Comment: wow, -last is slow! also, why didn't they just make a command called `head`?

Comment: @Neil, `-Last` is slow for the same reason `awk` would be slow for the same task: It has to consume the stream completely first. That's why `Get-Content -Tail` exists. And there is no `head` because it doesn't fit into the naming conventions, and its purpose is already served by `Select-Item`.

Comment: @neil @joey They have an alias for `-head`. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41626586/1081043

Comment: @wisbucky: That's a parameter alias for `-TotalCount`, not a command alias for `Get-Content`. I was referring to commands here, as was Neil.

Comment: can you update your example where you pipe it into a new file ?

Comment: @user702846: `Out-File`.

Comment: New home for [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx)

Answer (score 95):

Here are the built-in ways to do `head` and `tail`. Don't use pipes because if you have a large file, it will be extremely slow. Using these built-in options will be extremely fast even for huge files.

```
gc log.txt -head 10 
gc log.txt -tail 10
gc log.txt -tail 10 -wait # equivalent to tail -f
```

Comment: but [Joey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682024/how-to-do-what-head-tail-more-less-sed-do-in-powershell#comment60271566_9682594) seems to indicate the exact opposite! how do I know who to trust or which (built-in) method is most efficient?

Comment: @NH My answer is in agreement with Joey's comment. His comment says "-Last is slow... That's why Get-Content -Tail exists." `| select -last` uses pipes. I'm using `-tail` without pipes. But if you do ever find two conflicting answers, you could probably trust the person with a much higher reputation. Also, you can simply try the two methods on a large file. It will be very obvious on a large file.

Comment: I also discovered Select-Object, which you can then alias as "grep" :)

Comment: Noting that `-Head` and `-First` are aliases for `-TotalCount`

Answer (score 9):

`more.exe` exists on Windows, ports of `less` are easily found (and the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/), PSCX, includes one).

PowerShell doesn't really provide any alternative to separate programs for either, but for structured data `Out-Grid` can be helpful.

`Head` and `Tail` can both be emulated with `Select-Object` using the `-First` and `-Last` parameters respectively.

`Sed` functions are all available but structured rather differently. The filtering options are available in `Where-Object` (or via `Foreach-Object` and some state for ranges). Other, transforming, operations can be done with `Select-Object` and `Foreach-Object`.

However as PowerShell passes (.NET) objects – with all their typed structure, eg. dates remain `DateTime` instances – rather than just strings, which each command needs to parse itself, much of `sed` and other such programs are redundant.

Comment: Brilliant. gc does not seem to support pipe input. when I want to filter a command's output, I am using "...exe ...|select-object -first 20|select-object -last 1"

Answer (score 3):

"-TotalCount" in this instance responds exactly like "-head". You have to use -TotalCount or -head to run the command like that. But -TotalCount is misleading - it does not work in ACTUALLY giving you ANY counts...

```
gc -TotalCount 25 C:\scripts\logs\robocopy_report.txt
```

The above script, tested in PS 5.1 is the SAME response as below...

```
gc -head 25 C:\scripts\logs\robocopy_report.txt
```

So then just use '-head 25" already!

Comment: `-TotalCount` behaviour is as documented. Behaves like Unix `head` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1 "Specifies the number of lines from the beginning of a file or other item. The default is -1 (all lines). You can use the TotalCount parameter name or its aliases, First or Head."

Answer (score 2):

If you need to query large (or small) log files on Windows, the best tool I have found is Microsoft's free [Log Parser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659).  You can call it from PowerShell if you want and it will do all the heavy lifting for you, and very fast too.

Comment: thanks anyway, My enviroment is Win2k8R2 which is not in System requirements of Log Parser2.2

Comment: That download URL is no longer available. Try `winget install Microsoft.LogParser` or https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659

Answer (score 0):

I got some better solutions:

```
gc log.txt -ReadCount 5 | %{$_;throw "pipeline end!"} # head
gc log.txt | %{$num=0;}{$num++;"$num $_"}             # cat -n
gc log.txt | %{$num=0;}{$num++; if($num -gt 2 -and $num -lt 7){"$num $_"}} # sed
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$Push_Pop = $ErrorActionPreference #Suppresses errors
$ErrorActionPreference = “SilentlyContinue” #Suppresses errors
#Script
    #gc .\output\*.csv -ReadCount 5 | %{$_;throw "pipeline end!"} # head
    #gc .\output\*.csv | %{$num=0;}{$num++;"$num $_"}             # cat -n
    gc .\output\*.csv | %{$num=0;}{$num++; if($num -gt 2 -and $num -lt 7){"$num $_"}} # sed
#End Script 
$ErrorActionPreference = $Push_Pop #Suppresses errors
```

You don't get all the errors with the pushpop code
BTW, your code only works with the "sed" option. All the rest ignores anything but gc and path.

Comment: This does suppress errroractionpreference... I use this in my $profile all the time...
'ErrorActionPreference = “SilentlyContinue” #Suppresses errors'