# Adding wcf service references in client application leads time consuming

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, wcf

In my wcf project i have 8 long services and one service which is having nearly 500 methods , In the client application we added service references, the problem we are facing is when we are updating small code in the service code i need to update the service references so at that time it has been taken nearly 10-20 min of time to update because of large service. Is there any alternative approach is there to achieve this drawback....

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 Updating Service Reference \*crazy\* Slow (like 5 minutes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389387/vs2010-updating-service-reference-crazy-slow-like-5-minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic options: auto building of the proxy (what happens when you update references in .NET) and manual building of the proxy. Most people pick the first.

There is a step you can try, which is create a service with only the new methods and create a proxy. You then copy over the proxy methods and any new types exposed. This is faster, but a bit more complex. And it will take a bit of trial and error (hope you have source code), as you get used to what to copy and what is duplication. Fortunately, if this fails, refreshing will fix anything you mess up (just plan refresh around lunch time?).

A better long term strategy is to think about what you are exposing on the web service and refactor. You can combine methods, eliminate duplicates (and possibly refactor their purpose into other methods). You may also want to look at cohesion of the methods and break into smaller services. This is not a free action, as you have to think about the DevOps side (one service easier to deploy than many).

To avoid this in the future, you need more planning on services before building. This may require a change in business, as well as IT.

Comment: Thank you  Gregory, but we created client and service as different project so it is not possbilble to create a proxy for the service reference..