# The difference between "Service Reference" in the project, and in a reference project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, service-reference

What is the difference between

@1:Add Service Reference in the MAIN (project)

and

@2:Add Service Reference in the SUB(project),then, use "SUB" as a reference for MAIN

@2 solves my slowness, but i have no idea what can be different.

The difference between #1 and #2 maybe, might, could provide some hints of the real cause. Any thoughts would be thankful.

---------------Below is previous question------------------

I have encountered an issue that Service Reference cause debug slow, the browser will busy for 30 min - 1 hr until the initial page is up.

This is not just [Visual Studio debugging/loading very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984/visual-studio-debugging-loading-very-slow), i tried everything mentioned there, no help.

However i did notice removing the service reference, or add as "Web Reference" will solve the issue.
But, unfortunately, i have to use as service reference orz.

I tried 2010, 2012 in Win7 and Win10. net is 4.0, both same situation.

Not really sure about the cause, any thoughts would be appreciated.

++March 19, 2018:

I just discovered that VS can be run in windows safe mode (with network) orz.
Same result when i tested in safe mode.

-> I started to doubt the issue is not within my computer.

Could it be the connection between my computer and those service hosting? And or the firewall/AV/Domain settings...etc on and between the computers. (nothing i can change anyway...)

-> Is there a way to prevent VS to (re)build the files for the services?

*or, does VS "verify" the services on run?

**move those to another project works, but I can't change the project..

[image]

Comment: An hour is quite a bit beyond "very slow".  You'll need to regain control over this machine, start killing off the shrink-wrapped malware.

Comment: There are other computers don't have this "long", however there are too many factors that may cause this (AV, firewall, connection, account permissions ...etc.), so far i am running out of ideas~_~

Comment: @Alex C, If other computers have no this issue, if possible, just compare the debugging settings under project property and Tools->Options->Debugging, maybe all machines use the default settings. In addition, please also visit the "add service reference" window, whether certain settings will also impact the debugging performance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389387/vs2010-updating-service-reference-crazy-slow-like-5-minutes. Of course, if still no help, maybe you really need to think about your Windows Environment like the third party tools, network connection or others in your side.

Comment: @Fletch, thanks for pointing that. I did try duplicate set options, also ask the user to login my computer to try. No luck.
In this case i can't use anything else than service reference (not something that I can decide)

Comment: @Alex C, Do you disable the "Microsoft symbol Servers" option under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols? View the debugging result Please also close all third party tools in your side like firewall or others.

Comment: @Jack yes i did try that and also download symbol (then uncheck the symbol servers). I tested in safe mode, same issue, therefore firewall and AV looks like is not a cause (at least very minimal)

Comment: @Alex C, If your project run normally in safe mode, please check that whether your VS installed certain add-ins or extension tools before, disable them, view the result. Please also disable the Visual Studio Hosting process option under your project property.

Comment: @Jack its a clean install, and the only add-on is the web development thing from installation (else can't run debug). I meant windows's safe mode, not VS's safe mode orz.

Comment: @Alex C., If so, it would be not the VS IDE issue, it would be related to your windows Environment. Maybe you could clean up your windows cache files, or add a new user in your windows, view the result with the new user.

Comment: @Jack yea i tried it on, off, re-download, but no luck at all. I have updated my question, I think (hope?) looking at the different between @1 and @2 may give me some new ideas.